# Number of discrete eigenvalues of the Schrodinger operator.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm trying to prove the theorem:

*Number of eigenvalues of the equation
$$-\psi_{xx}(x)+u(x)\psi(x)=-p^2\psi(x),\,\, -\infty<x<+\infty,\,\,p>0$$
($u(x)$ is real and rapidly tends to zero at infinity)
equals the number of  zeros  $\varphi(x)$,
where $$\varphi_{xx}(x)=u(x)\varphi(x),\,\,\varphi(-\infty)=1,\,\,\varphi_x(-\infty)=0.$$*
Please tell me where to start, because I don’t see any ideas connecting the spectrum of one with the number of zeros of another equation

Comment: Where did you encounter this theorem?

Comment: user619894
Book: Calogero F., Degasperis A. Spectral Transform and Solitons

Comment: Don't know much about solitons, but I do know that the n'th Schrodinger state has n-1 nodes. Maybe the maximal bound state of $\psi$ can be connected to $\varphi$. The nodes (zeros) of the maximal bound state + 1 is the number of bound eigenstates.

Comment: Yes, what you said is Sturm's oscillation theorem. "Maybe the maximal bound state of ψ can be connected to φ." --This would actually solve the problem.  However, how to establish this connection. And I'm worried about the nonzero boundary conditions. for $\varphi$

Comment: I suspect that once you find the maximally bound state you can gauge away the $p^2$ term by redefining $y=e^{-px}\psi(x)$ or something, and that will "tilt" the wave function at $-\infty$. Just an intuition, sorry.

Comment: Will there not be a $\psi_x(x)$ term?

Comment: Maybe, maybe it will vanish at the maximal bound state. As I said, this is pure speculation. You asked "where to start". This is where I would start.

Comment: Thanks.. I am starting))